# PAssing DTO to ServiceStack using POST

Tags: servicestack

in my service i have the following request:

```
[Route(@"/api/adddevice", Verbs = "POST")]
public class AddDeviceRequest : IReturn<AddDeviceResponse> 
{
    public DTOTargetDevice TargetDevice { get; set; }
}
```

It uses the following DTO:

```
public class DTOTargetDevice
{
    private string _guid = string.Empty;
    public string GUID
    {
        get { return _guid; }
        set { _guid = DTOUtils.GetGUID(value); }
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string[] PropertiesName { get; set; }
    public string[] PropertiesValue { get; set; }
}
```

From a C# client, everything works fine, but when i try to call it, TargetDevice is always null.
This is the javascript code i'm using:

```
        var parms = {};
    parms.targetDevice = {};
    parms.targetDevice.guid=guid();
    parms.targetDevice.deviceName = guid();
    parms.targetDevice.type = sDeviceType;
    parms.targetDevice.propertiesName = (propsName);
    parms.targetDevice.propertiesValue = (propsValue);
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    }
    var promise = $http.post("http://" + sIP + ":20001/api/adddevice", parms, config).then(function (response) {
        var result = response.data.result;
        console.log("Added Device: " + result);
        return result;
    });
```

This is the json, taken from Chrom Developer window:

> {"targetDevice":{"guid":"e7461703-1b4b-7cd3-6263-3ac0935fb6f7","deviceName":"11e08b8f-d030-8f69-a469-4a1300aa49bf","type":"HTTPDevice","propertiesName":["Name","Acronym"],"propertiesValue":["Device","Device"]}}:

I've tried several options, but i'm always receiveng a null exception on TargetDevice within the request.

I've already read in other threads that simple objects is preferred, but in other services i have even more complex DTO. 
Do you have any suggestion about that?

Thanks
Leo

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting you:

> > This is the json, taken from Chrom Developer window:

The important word from your sentence is this: **`json`**. So make sure you specify the correct content type when making your request. You need to be consistent in what you claim to be sending and what you are actually sending to the server:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
```

In your example you were claiming that you were sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;` and then dumping a JSON string, how do you expect the server to be able to cope with this confusion?

I guess that Angular or whatever this `$http.post` function that you are using will automatically `JSON.stringify` the `parms` object before sending it to the server. Maybe it will even automatically add the `application/json` content type request header, so you could completely get rid of this `config` variable of yours in this case.

Comment: If i use ContentType: application/json, it's not passed as a POST request.
From Chrome:
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:20001/api/adddevice
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:20001

Comment: What do you mean it's not passed as a POST request? What verb does the `$http.post` method use?

Comment: Ohhh, OPTIONS request is failing. It means that you seem to be doing some cross domain AJAX call, are you? Does your server support CORS? In order to be able to make cross domain AJAX requests you will need to configure your server API to support CORS headers. Make sure that your ServiceStack endpoint will not return 404 to an OPTIONS request but rather it will respect the CORS protocol, otherwise you will not be able to call it from a javascript client hosted on another domain.

Comment: Yes. It supports that. Problem appeared when i moved my Request DTO from simple object with just string properties, to a complex object like the one described before

Comment: It doesn't seem to support it properly, if it did, it wouldn't have returned 404 to an OPTIONS request. I guess you might need to consult ServiceStack's documentation in order to properly implement CORS in your API layer. Otherwise you will be out of luck of calling it from a javascript client hosted on a different domain. The proper response to a CORS preflight request should be 200, with the corresponding CORS response headers indicating to the client which domains and headers are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
Instead of using in SetConfig()

```
                GlobalResponseHeaders =
            {
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
                { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },
            },
```

I've used:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
```

Thanks guys!
LEo